# Здравствуйте пытаюсь запустить стим на линкс арч стим не может загрузить обновления при первом запуске

Tags: linux, archlinux, steam

Здравтсвуйте я новичок в линукс арче при первой установке стим выскакивает вот эта вот ошибка в интернете не смог найти как решить данную проблему и извините за то что без знаков препинания я еще неразобрался с настройкой раскладки клавиатуры
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: [Порты, необходимые для работы Steam](https://help.steampowered.com/ru/faqs/view/2EA8-4D75-DA21-31EB)